# How does Windows know what program to open a file with?

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

I just noticed that when I view the `.sln` files on my computer, that some have a v7.1 icon, some have a v9 icon, and some have a v10 icon (depending on what version of Visual Studio created them).  It appears that Windows distinguishing which files get which icons, possibly via some sort of "MIME type" for files apart from the extension.

Could I use that functionality to detect which filetype a user selects from the default MFC SaveAs dialog if two filetypes share an extension?

Comment: I think Visual Studio may be a special case -- Microsoft has some crazy intermediary executable that figures out the versioning and passes .sln files to the appropriate version of VS. That's not to say it's not possible to do what you're asking, it just may be less common than it first appears.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144122%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: Confirming what dlev commented; it uses a shell extension to show the icons.

Comment: @Praetorian: Realistically, one is a superset of the other, so I can easily tell the format from the filesize, like a bmp header.  But I was hoping there was some magic trick I could use.

Comment: @Praetorian: You should post that as an answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck Done; I also dug into the VS intermediary executable a little bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of Visual Studio, the `.sln` files are associated with *Microsoft Visual Studio Version Selector*, which, on my machine, is installed under *"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\MSEnv\VSLauncher.exe"*

This executable must parse the solution file to determine the version, and then present the right icon to explorer.

In the general case, file associations for a given file type are present in the registry, under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

But in your case, I think you're just going to have to read the file contents to determine which one it is. Hopefully there's something easily distinguishable between the two.

Comment: It will be a shell extension in-proc COM server, rather than the launcher executable, that presents the right icon to the shell. But otherwise your analysis is accurate I would say.